# Why is CSS `resize` property inherited on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, resize

I thought that elements didn't inherit `resize` property from their parents, but I have just seen that on Chromium they do:

- Screenshot of Chromium's inspector:

  [image]
- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3rdj4/

I have searched it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize), and it says "*Inherited: no*"

Then, I have searched it on [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#resize), and it says "*Inherited: no*" too.

Why is it inherited on Chromium, then?

Should I use...

```
* {
    resize: none;
}
```

... at the top of the document from now on?

**Note**: I use Chromium 30.0.1592.0 (216775)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is known bug, which was reported 7th February 2013

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175009